# Trying to run RecursiveDirectoryIterator as a specific user but getting Permission denied error

Tags: php

I have a php script that I am running from the command line (mac) to do some data wrangling. To traverse multiple files/folders I am using this:

```
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/Users/jmlockl2/Desktop/small_set');
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
    ....
```

If I run this as my regular user (just run `php script.php`) it works as it should. However, I need to access some files in a web directory so I need to run the script as `_www` user. So when I run  `sudo -u _www php script5.php` I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/Users/jmlockl2/Desktop/small_set): Failed to open directory: Permission denied in /Users/jmlockl2/Sites/crisisprep-6/custom/script5.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jmlockl2/Sites/crisisprep-6/custom/script5.php(39): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('/Users/jmlockl2...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/jmlockl2/Sites/crisisprep-6/custom/script5.php on line 39

Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/Users/jmlockl2/Desktop/small_set): Failed to open directory: Permission denied in /Users/jmlockl2/Sites/crisisprep-6/custom/script5.php:39
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jmlockl2/Sites/crisisprep-6/custom/script5.php(39): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('/Users/jmlockl2...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/jmlockl2/Sites/crisisprep-6/custom/script5.php on line 39
```

The files I am accessing are in `/Users/jmlockl2/Desktop/small_set` and I've tried opening this directory up completely and also changing the owner of the folder to `_www` but nothing works. Her are the permissions on that directory:

```
ls -la small_set
total 32
drwxrwxrwx@ 17 _www      _www     544 Aug 16 12:52 .
drwx------@ 23 jmlockl2  staff    736 Sep  7 11:18 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 _www      _www   14340 Sep  7 11:37 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwx@ 42 _www      _www    1344 Jun 22 03:06 101-ANDA ACER
...
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you change owner of parent of `small_set` directory? Or change its permissions so `_www` user can access it? I'd say `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` fails on that directory perms

Comment: Jonny, see the last code snippet above. _www owns the small_set directory.

Comment: Yeah I see, I replicated this setup locally. Created parent of `small_set` owned by my user, all works fine. Passing ownership of equivalent of small_set parent to another user than mine makes RecursiveDirectoryIterator throw same error as yours.